# Le Petit Tourette

Tags: rules, etiquette

A kid I occasionally see on tournaments has a tic - he makes compulsive noises. Kids obviously have more understanding of such stuff - noone ever complained about being disturbed or made any ado about it at all.

Now, if he will play adult tourneys in a few years. Hmm. Should I ever play him, well, I could care less about the BBC Big Band Orchestra marching through the tournament hall, but others are easily disturbed.

What would you do as an arbiter? (The question of course generalizes to a bad cough or likewise any potential disturbance a player can neither control nor turn off.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Article 12 of the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023) defines the role of the arbiter. 12.2 specifies the things that the arbiter shall do and in particular:

> 12.2.6    take special measures in the interests of disabled players and those who need medical attention

FIDE makes every effort to encourage and facilitate the fullest participation of players with disabilities and requires that its arbiters do likewise.

If you have ever played with or against a blind player you will know that they call out their moves, their opponents are required to do likewise and then they usually speak the opponent's moves into a recording device. Hence the concept of a player with a disability making noises that would not be acceptable in player without disability should be familiar to all arbiters.

I have arbited in an open tournament with players rated 1900 - 2400 where one of the players had a nervous twitch every couple of seconds. Everybody in the tournament understood that this was a disability and nobody said anything. Obviously, nor did I.

I would expect exactly the same to apply to a player with the disability you describe.

Comment: Most definitely. (I only hope that his further opponents see it the same!)